# How to give style Material-ui Select-field Dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui select-field component

```
<SelectField
   multiple={true} 
   hintText="Checkbox Filters"
   dropDownMenuProps={{
     iconButton:<ActionHome />,
   }}
   className="checkbox-com"
   underlineStyle={{display:'none'}}
   hintStyle={{bottom:'13px', overflow: 'hidden',  whiteSpace: 'nowrap', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', width: 
   'calc(100% - 40px)', color: '#757575', fontWeight: 500}}
   labelStyle={{top: 0, paddingRight: 40, height: 48, lineHeight: '48px'}}
   iconStyle={{top: 2,right: 10, fill: '#757575', width: 44, height: 44}}
   style={{maxWidth: '200px', minWidth: 200, width: 'auto', lineHeight: '22px', height: 48, fontSize: 
   14}}>
 <List>
     <ListItem
       leftCheckbox={<Checkbox />}
       primaryText="Project 1"
       innerDivStyle={{fontSize: 14, paddingLeft: 60}}/>
     <ListItem
       leftCheckbox={<Checkbox />}
       primaryText="Project 2"
       innerDivStyle={{fontSize: 14, paddingLeft: 60}}/>
     <ListItem
       leftCheckbox={<Checkbox />}
       primaryText="Project 3"
       innerDivStyle={{fontSize: 14, paddingLeft: 60}}/>
  </List>
 </SelectField>
```

But they showing like this

[image]

But i need to show like this

[image]

**Please tel me how can i style dropdown menu like this**

Comment: how did you fixed it? Can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are looking for is

```
anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'left'}}
```

On the `DropDownMenu`

Answer (score 0):

Its the default behavior of `Material ui select field` but you can override that

```
.mat-select-panel-wrap {
    margin-top: 36px;//Its the height ot your selectbox
}
```

Use `!important` in case if its doesn't override